# How to prevent Pico.css to take over as the default css?

Tags: javascript, css

I really like Pico, but it conflicts with other libraries I use when it tries to be the main driver of all the styles of e.g. form elements.

I would like to run Pico in a mode, where it is isn't affecting anything, unless i would write something like `class="pico"` or something similar, then it would apply its styles to this particular element.

Is that possible?

Comment: Conflicting CSS is never fun, you should get into the practice of working with single style sheets and modifying them or creating your own from scratch (with CSS reset sheet). With your supplied description of the problem I couldn't give you an easy answer making this question invalid. Perhaps try ChatGPT for help.

Comment: I'd never heard of that framework before, but at a glance of their introduction page it sounds like the main point of it is to be the "default", to apply semantically to the markup rather than needing explicit classes and other customizations to use it.  It sounds like what you want is in direct opposition to what the tool is designed to do.  You may be able to get around this by modifying their CSS to add your `.pico` class to all selectors, which you'd have to do any time you update the library.

Comment: You could ask the developer(s). The website contains a mail address: lucas@larroche.com, a GitHub link: https://github.com/picocss/pico/issues and a Twitter link: https://twitter.com/picocss. They can answer your question or even implement it as a new feature.

Answer (score -1):

Following the comments, there are no way to do this automatically.

The only way would be to do it manually, as David mention in the comments:

*You may be able to get around this by modifying their CSS to add your .pico class to all selectors, which you'd have to do any time you update the library.*

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is based on guesses in the comments. It could be correct, but it could also be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I acknowledge that the entire question and answer are weak, and won't  accept my own answer. For what it's worth, I managed to get a solution running with using Davids suggestion, adding ".pico" to all selectors, using ChatGPT for efficiency. This is not a good solution, since 1: I don't know if ChatGPT did any errors (but looks fine so far), and 2: Can't easily update Pico.css (alltho Pico.css hasn't been updated for three months, so this particular release seems stable enough, for a little while atleast).